# Как подключить DLL без Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#

Я гуглил, смотрел, всюду делается dll в vs, а потом там же и подключается. Меня интересует как ее подключить без vs? Создать библиотеку я узнал как - напрямую через .NET Framework (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe /t:library имя файла), а вот как ее подключить потом не знаю, может подскажите?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Я такого никогда не делал, но предполагаю, что через какую-то стандартную утилиту можно это сделать. По сути, нам нужно изменить манифест сборки(dll), добавив в него ссылку на другую dll.

Comment: [-reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/reference-compiler-option)

Comment: В книге Эндрю Троелсена описана работа с компилятором из командной строки.

Comment: А вообще, для сборки проектов рекомендуется использовать [MSBuild](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild?view=vs-2019). Библиотеки подключаются в файле *.csproj вашего проекта. Можете открыть его в текстовом редакторе и посмотреть, как там задаются ссылки на сборки.